# Convert html table to List of Lists in Python

Tags: python

I have this code that converts a specific html table data cell into a list:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_table = pd.read_html('https://kefirprobiotics.com/for_testing_only')
df = my_table[0]
my_list = [int(v) for v in '-'.join(df['Position']).split('-')]
print(my_list)
```

The code is fine, but what is the elegant way of converting the list from:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

to this instead:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],[4, 5, 6, 7],[7, 8, 9, 10],[10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of joining the rows with `'-'.join(df['Position'])`, just iterate over each row, and create a sublist for each.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_table = pd.read_html('https://kefirprobiotics.com/for_testing_only')
df = my_table[0]
my_list = [[int(v) for v in row.split('-')] for row in df['Position']]
print(my_list)
```

Asuming you want to keep the rows/sublists from the [original table](https://kefirprobiotics.com/for_testing_only) you put in the question.